# Complexity of merging storyboard file

Tags: ios, git, svn, storyboard

I heard in iOS development it is risk to use storyboard if many user edit it at the same time. Merging will result too many conflict and difficult to edit conflicts.

It happened under SVN version controlling. Is it any different better experience under GIT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the same. I am using GIT and it still is difficult to solve storyboard conflicts.

If you are working in a team, I suggest you to **create a storyboard for each theme in the app so that every member can work on a separate storyboard** and don't get conflicts. If all team needs to work on the same theme, let only one person touch the storyboard (UI), while others work on network managers, data objects, reusable pieces, etc.